# How to get the correct item when the SearchView filters result display in the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

[image]I have a`RecyclerView` and a `SearchView` in my Activity .. the `SearchView` updates the `RecyclerView` as expected by filtering the `RecyclerView` but the `get(position)` is not updating and the `RecyclerView` `onClick` triggers the first item in the list  if i click the first listitem after the results are filtered..

My Activity is as follows:

```
public class MangalStuti extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
private List<Name> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
 //  EditText editTextSearch;
//  ArrayList<String> names;
private Adapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mangal_stuti_activity);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
   // editTextSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);

    mAdapter = new Adapter(movieList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    // row click listener
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Name name = movieList.get(position);
            String text = name.getTitle();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (text == "Apple"){
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(),Apple.class));
            }
            if (text == "Tiger"){
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(),Animal.class));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));

    prepareMovieData();
}

private void prepareMovieData() {
    Name movie = new Name("Apple", "Fruit", "2018");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Name("Tiger", "Animal", "2018");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Name("Paris", "Place", "2018");
    movieList.add(movie);



    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.actionsearch);
    SearchView searchView=(SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    newText=newText.toLowerCase();
    ArrayList<Name> newlist=new ArrayList<>();
    for(Name name:movieList)
    {
        String getName=name.getTitle().toLowerCase();
        if(getName.contains(newText)){
            newlist.add(name);

        }
    }
    mAdapter.filter(newlist);
    return true;
}
}
```

My Adapter class

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <Adapter.MyViewHolder>{

private List<Name> movieList;
private ArrayList<Name> arraylist;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, year, genre;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
    }

}

public Adapter(List<Name> movieList) {
    this.movieList = movieList;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Name>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(movieList);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Name name = movieList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(name.getTitle());
    holder.genre.setText(name.getGenre());
    holder.year.setText(name.getYear());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movieList.size();
}

public void filter(ArrayList<Name> newList)
{
    movieList=new ArrayList<>();
    movieList.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Name Class

```
public class Name {
private String title, genre, year;

public Name() {
}

public Name(String title, String genre, String year) {
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.year = year;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;

}

public void setTitle(String name) {
    this.title = name;

}

public String getYear() {
    return year;

}

public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;

}

public String getGenre() {
    return genre;

}

public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;

}
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question, didn't understand what issue you have.

Comment: you will get the position of filtered list ,for example initial you have 10 item in the list, then it will return position till 10, but after filter you get the only 5 items out of 10 items then it will return the position for filtered list not for the original list.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma ... i repharsed the question and also added an image to explain my problem..

Comment: Share your adapter class, basically you need to use adapter method to get the movie for that position instead getting back from original list

Comment: @KrishnaSharma .. my Adapter class is updated to the question...

Comment: i used adapter method only .. `Name movie = movieList.get(position);` isn't it correct? @KrishnaSharma

Comment: See the answer, it should work fine.

Comment: no that is not correct. movieList will always be the original/master list not the filtered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method in adapter class like below

```
public List<Name> getMovieList(){
  return movieList;
}
```

Then use below code to get the selected movie

```
 // row click listener
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Name name = mAdapter.getMovieList().get(position); // Important one
            String text = name.getTitle();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (text == "Apple"){
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(),Apple.class));
            }
            if (text == "Tiger"){
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(),Animal.class));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
```